# HardhatError: HH17: The input value cannot be normalized to a BigInt: Unsupported type undefined

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to develop a simple dapp,I'm using hardhat with the last version that comes with etherjs.
I have a function inside the contract that can receive amount of ether:

```
function addInheritance(address _wallet) payable external onlyOwner{
        ...
}
```

I'm writing the testing script for this function, here's the code:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
describe("Will", function () {
  let Will, will;
  before(async () => {
    Will = await ethers.getContractFactory("Will");
    will = await Will.deploy("0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("20.0"),
    });
    await will.deployed();
  });

  it("Should add an inheritance", async () => {
    await will.addInheritance("0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E", {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("5.0"),
    });
    expect(
      will.inheritance["0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E"]
    ).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("5.0"));
  });
});
```

After running the test I got the following error:

```
Should add an inheritance:
     HardhatError: HH17: The input value cannot be normalized to a BigInt: Unsupported type undefined
```

I don't know where is the problem because I'm using the ether convertor to convert bigNumbers: ethers.utils.parseEther("5.0")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have await inside expect statement. You are getting a Promise which cannot be parsed as bigInt